# Script adding not working

Tags: php, mysql, asp.net-web-api

### Introduction

I am trying to make a API. Reading from the db works fine...
Writing to it however is failing.

The weird part is when i copy the query error_log print-out and paste it into PHPMyAdmin, It added the object correctly.

### Code

**index.php**

```
...
 else if($tag == 'addIngredient'){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $cal = $_POST['cal'];
    $fat = $_POST['fat'];
    error_log("name=".$name." cal=".$cal."fat=".$fat);
    if(!$db->addIngredient($name,$cal,$fat)){
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["error_msg"] = "addIngredient failed";
    }

 }
...
```

**BDFunctions.php**

```
...
public function addIngredient($name, $cal, $fat){
    $query= "INSERT INTO `ingredient` (`name`, `cal`, `fat`) VALUES('".$name."', ".$cal.", ".$fat.");";
    error_log($query);
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if($result){return true;}
    return false;
}
...
```

I get these print outs in my apache log:...

> [Wed Apr 29 20:46:58 2015] [error] [client 192.168.1.9] name=testName cal=50fat=20
>   [Wed Apr 29 20:46:58 2015] [error] [client 192.168.1.9] INSERT INTO `ingredient` (`name`, `cal`, `fat`) VALUES('testName', 50, 20);

Comment: is your program work correctly or not? i mean if works correctly than why you worried about the Apache log.

Comment: You don't need the semicolon in the string at the end of your query. Start by taking that out.  Also, on a somewhat unrelated topic, you should really consider porting this code over to MySQLi or PDO.  The `mysql_*` family of functions is deprecated.

Comment: ohh yaa... i think that `semicolon` can be issue.

Comment: the semicolon doesn't matter. It doesnt improve any preformance by removing it, does it ?

Comment: semicolon as in ";" ? lolz

Comment: `$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());` Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: The **`mysql_`** inteface is deprecated. Use **`mysqli`** or **`PDO`** instead. Including potentially unsafe values in SQL text leads to SQL Injection vulnerabilities. You can't mix-n-match calls from the libraries. Choose an interface library, and use the functions from that library.

Comment: One thing though, `if(!$db->addIngredient($name,$cal,$fat)){` and `mysql_` functions. I think your query's not the same API or *vice-versa*. Hard to say for sure, but `mysql_` doesn't use object oriented methods. Different MySQL APIs do not intermix with each other, if that is what is going on here.

Comment: @spencer7593 , this is just a test project, no worries :P -- the values must be right since it added the object when i copy the error_log query print-out and paste it into MyPHPAdmin

Comment: @Fred-ii- i've added these error reporting functions, Didn't pass me any extra info though :/

Comment: @KoenDemonie: No worries. My observation is that developers that write code vulnerable to SQL Injection in "just a test project" tend to continue that same pattern (of writing code vulnerable to SQL Injection) when working on other projects as well.

Comment: @KoenDemonie For the semicolon, it should work, but the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) say that your queries shouldn't end with a semicolon.  As for the error, do as Fred suggested and use the error reporting function `mysql_error()` to get MySQL's last error.  Have you debugged along the way to make sure you have a good connection to the MySQL server and have the correct DB selected?

Comment: @spencer7593 , thank you for the heads-up ! euhm i just want to be able to insert some data into the db. I'll look into the SQL-injection afterwards...

Comment: @Crackertastic Yes, The read functions work like a charm...

Comment: @KoenDemonie There must be something else to it that isn't present with the information given.  I ran your code on my machine and it appears to be adding things just fine.

Comment: And to reinforce what @spencer7593 is talking about.  If this is just a test project then it is the perfect opportunity to begin testing/practicing with an API like mysqli or PDO.  Both can make use of prepared statements, which is a great tool to assist in preventing SQL injection.  Most of the information you will find around preventing such an attack with likely mention the use of prepared statements.

Comment: @Crackertastic , perhaps it is depreciated, but this is my question. StackExchange is meant to help solve the problem.....

Comment: depricated or not, adding an item to the db should be possible, not ?

Comment: @KoenDemonie Fair enough. My intent was to raise awareness on some advantages of the other APIs, that's all.  As for your question, the insert statement works fine when I run it on my local machine. There is another piece of the problem that isn't shown here.

Comment: Hmm thank you I'll look into it. And I do appreciate the awareness but it was already said a few times :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it isn't a question. There is no question asked. What's posted is some code, and the output that the code writes to the log file, and a description of some observed behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should catch the `mysql_error()` someplace in there. I also added `sprintf()` to help prepare the statement better. Also I see no reference to your DB Link (`$link`, `$con`, etc)

```
public function addIngredient($name, $cal, $fat){
    $query= sprintf("INSERT INTO `ingredient` (`name`, `cal`, `fat`) VALUES ('%s', %d, %d);",
       $name,
       $cal,
       $fat
    );
    error_log($query);
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if($result){return true;}
    error_log(mysql_errno($link) . ": " . mysql_error($link));
    return false;
}
```